# Using the COUNTIF function

Tags: excel, function

I am trying to use the `COUNTIF` function in excel to count the number of times a cell is used.
For instance, consider a column A as defined below:

[image]

To count how many times `2.5U` appears (clearly it is twice), I used the command `=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)` which returns a result of `0`. Why is this the case?

Comment: No repro. I get `2`.

Comment: Works for me. Perhaps check for circular references or manual calculation

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem with Excel. It's a circular reference if your formula is in column A along with the data since you're including that cell with `A:A`. Don't put it in the same column (put `=COUNTIF(A:A, A2)` in colum B, for example), or be more specific. If your formula is in call `A50`, then use `=COUNTIF(A2:A49, A2)`. Don't allow the range to include the formula.

Comment: Does it matter that my first row contains no numerals?

Comment: Try =COUNTIF(A:A,"2.5*")

Comment: @lurker This worked. I had to use a different column when applying my function.